# Codeigniter: Share database config between applications

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have two applications inside one Codeigniter instance (Codeigniter 3.0). I need to share database config between applications. In each application I have config:

```
include_once 'application/shared/config/database.php';
```

But I have error on application start:

> No database connection settings were found in the database config
>   file.

I decide to check variable

```
include_once 'application/shared/config/database.php';
var_dump(isset($db));
```

And what I see?

> boolean true
>
> boolean false

I'm trying to find difference between DB initializations, but not founded yet.

**include** instead of **include_once** is solution, but I think it is not correct.

What is the best solution?

Comment: what do you mean you have to make connection with two database?

Comment: @saty, I have two applications (for example, main website and subdomain site). I want one database config for them

Comment: these two application inside single codeignator or two different codeignator

Comment: one codeigniter instance, two applications inside

Comment: if you use single codeignitor the you can easily share database no need to include your connection

Comment: @saty Show me how, please?